# SilverLight 5 toolkit

Tags: wcf, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm working an application that is based on Silverlight 5. It's framework 4.5 is MVVM architecture and implemented by Prism. I'm using silverlight 5 toolkit too.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                               
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
            xmlns:inputToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
            xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
            xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"    
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"  
            xmlns:controlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
            xmlns:input="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input"
            xmlns:controlsPrimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
            xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
            xmlns:telerikNavigation="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"    
            xmlns:telerikTabControl="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.TabControl;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
            xmlns:telerikNavigationPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UFone_CRM_UI.Themes"
            xmlns:dataPrimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:Telerik_Windows_Controls_GridView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView" xmlns:telerikGridView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView">

<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Calendar">
                <StackPanel x:Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <controlsPrimitives:CalendarItem x:Name="CalendarItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem}" IsEnabled="True" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
<controlsPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="TextBox" Margin="0,0,20,0" Height="22" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Style="{StaticResource System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DatePickerTextBox}"/>
```

This sample buid successed but at runtime in InitializeComponent() method I got this Error =>

```
The type 'controlsPrimitives:CalendarItem' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built
The type 'controlsPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built
```

If I delete controls, CalenderItem or DatePickerTextBox the Error do not occur.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to System.Windows.Controls?